# Delphi different result from MD5 Hash functions

Tags: delphi, md5

I work with Delphi Berlin.
I try to migrate an old project and i'm stuck on login :).
I cannot replace the old function RivestStr from the md5 unit, with the new one MD5Hash.
In order to test the behavior I create a simple project with 2 buttons and 3 edits.

my problem is the fact that this 2 functions have different results.
and I'm not sure how to make the MD5Hash to give the same result as the RivestStr.

```
uses IdHashMessageDigest, idHash  

function  MD5Hash(Value : String) : String;
var workHash : TIdHashMessageDigest5;
begin
  try
    workHash := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
    Result   := workHash.HashStringAsHex(Value);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(workHash);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edResult.Text := MD5Hash(edPass.Text);
end;

procedure TForm5.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edRivest.Text := RivestStr(edPass.Text);
end;
```

---

```
unit md5;

interface

uses Windows, SysUtils, Classes;



type
  MD5Count = array[0..1] of DWORD;
  MD5State = array[0..3] of DWORD;
  MD5Block = array[0..15] of DWORD;
  MD5CBits = array[0..7] of Byte;
  MD5Digest = array[0..15] of Byte;
  MD5Buffer = array[0..63] of Byte;
  MD5Context = record
    State: MD5State;
    Count: MD5Count;
    Buffer: MD5Buffer;
  end;

procedure MD5Init(var Context: MD5Context);
procedure MD5Update(var Context: MD5Context; Input: pChar; Length: longword);
procedure MD5Final(var Context: MD5Context; var Digest: MD5Digest);

function MD5String(M: string): MD5Digest;
function MD5File(N: string): MD5Digest;
function MD5Print(D: MD5Digest): string;
function MD5Match(D1, D2: MD5Digest): Boolean;

function RivestStr(Str: string): string;
function RivestFile(FileName: string): string;


var

  PADDING: MD5Buffer = (
    $80, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00,
    $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00,
    $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00,
    $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00,
    $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00,
    $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00,
    $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00,
    $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00);

implementation






function F(x, y, z: DWORD): DWORD;
begin
  Result := (x and y) or ((not x) and z);
end;

function G(x, y, z: DWORD): DWORD;
begin
  Result := (x and z) or (y and (not z));
end;

function H(x, y, z: DWORD): DWORD;
begin
  Result := x xor y xor z;
end;

function I(x, y, z: DWORD): DWORD;
begin
  Result := y xor (x or (not z));
end;

procedure rot(var x: DWORD; n: BYTE);
begin
  x := (x shl n) or (x shr (32 - n));
end;

procedure FF(var a: DWORD; b, c, d, x: DWORD; s: BYTE; ac: DWORD);
begin
  inc(a, F(b, c, d) + x + ac);
  rot(a, s);
  inc(a, b);
end;

procedure GG(var a: DWORD; b, c, d, x: DWORD; s: BYTE; ac: DWORD);
begin
  inc(a, G(b, c, d) + x + ac);
  rot(a, s);
  inc(a, b);
end;

procedure HH(var a: DWORD; b, c, d, x: DWORD; s: BYTE; ac: DWORD);
begin
  inc(a, H(b, c, d) + x + ac);
  rot(a, s);
  inc(a, b);
end;

procedure II(var a: DWORD; b, c, d, x: DWORD; s: BYTE; ac: DWORD);
begin
  inc(a, I(b, c, d) + x + ac);
  rot(a, s);
  inc(a, b);
end;

procedure Encode(Source, Target: pointer; Count: longword);
var
  S: PByte;
  T: PDWORD;
  I: longword;
begin
  S := Source;
  T := Target;
  for I := 1 to Count div 4 do begin
    T^ := S^;
    inc(S);
    T^ := T^ or (S^ shl 8);
    inc(S);
    T^ := T^ or (S^ shl 16);
    inc(S);
    T^ := T^ or (S^ shl 24);
    inc(S);
    inc(T);
  end;
end;

procedure Decode(Source, Target: pointer; Count: longword);
var
  S: PDWORD;
  T: PByte;
  I: longword;
begin
  S := Source;
  T := Target;
  for I := 1 to Count do begin
    T^ := S^ and $ff;
    inc(T);
    T^ := (S^ shr 8) and $ff;
    inc(T);
    T^ := (S^ shr 16) and $ff;
    inc(T);
    T^ := (S^ shr 24) and $ff;
    inc(T);
    inc(S);
  end;
end;

procedure Transform(Buffer: pointer; var State: MD5State);
var
  a, b, c, d: DWORD;
  Block: MD5Block;
begin
  Encode(Buffer, @Block, 64);
  a := State[0];
  b := State[1];
  c := State[2];
  d := State[3];
  FF (a, b, c, d, Block[ 0],  7, $d76aa478);
  FF (d, a, b, c, Block[ 1], 12, $e8c7b756);
  FF (c, d, a, b, Block[ 2], 17, $242070db);
  FF (b, c, d, a, Block[ 3], 22, $c1bdceee);
  FF (a, b, c, d, Block[ 4],  7, $f57c0faf);
  FF (d, a, b, c, Block[ 5], 12, $4787c62a);
  FF (c, d, a, b, Block[ 6], 17, $a8304613);
  FF (b, c, d, a, Block[ 7], 22, $fd469501);
  FF (a, b, c, d, Block[ 8],  7, $698098d8);
  FF (d, a, b, c, Block[ 9], 12, $8b44f7af);
  FF (c, d, a, b, Block[10], 17, $ffff5bb1);
  FF (b, c, d, a, Block[11], 22, $895cd7be);
  FF (a, b, c, d, Block[12],  7, $6b901122);
  FF (d, a, b, c, Block[13], 12, $fd987193);
  FF (c, d, a, b, Block[14], 17, $a679438e);
  FF (b, c, d, a, Block[15], 22, $49b40821);
  GG (a, b, c, d, Block[ 1],  5, $f61e2562);
  GG (d, a, b, c, Block[ 6],  9, $c040b340);
  GG (c, d, a, b, Block[11], 14, $265e5a51);
  GG (b, c, d, a, Block[ 0], 20, $e9b6c7aa);
  GG (a, b, c, d, Block[ 5],  5, $d62f105d);
  GG (d, a, b, c, Block[10],  9,  $2441453);
  GG (c, d, a, b, Block[15], 14, $d8a1e681);
  GG (b, c, d, a, Block[ 4], 20, $e7d3fbc8);
  GG (a, b, c, d, Block[ 9],  5, $21e1cde6);
  GG (d, a, b, c, Block[14],  9, $c33707d6);
  GG (c, d, a, b, Block[ 3], 14, $f4d50d87);
  GG (b, c, d, a, Block[ 8], 20, $455a14ed);
  GG (a, b, c, d, Block[13],  5, $a9e3e905);
  GG (d, a, b, c, Block[ 2],  9, $fcefa3f8);
  GG (c, d, a, b, Block[ 7], 14, $676f02d9);
  GG (b, c, d, a, Block[12], 20, $8d2a4c8a);
  HH (a, b, c, d, Block[ 5],  4, $fffa3942);
  HH (d, a, b, c, Block[ 8], 11, $8771f681);
  HH (c, d, a, b, Block[11], 16, $6d9d6122);
  HH (b, c, d, a, Block[14], 23, $fde5380c);
  HH (a, b, c, d, Block[ 1],  4, $a4beea44);
  HH (d, a, b, c, Block[ 4], 11, $4bdecfa9);
  HH (c, d, a, b, Block[ 7], 16, $f6bb4b60);
  HH (b, c, d, a, Block[10], 23, $bebfbc70);
  HH (a, b, c, d, Block[13],  4, $289b7ec6);
  HH (d, a, b, c, Block[ 0], 11, $eaa127fa);
  HH (c, d, a, b, Block[ 3], 16, $d4ef3085);
  HH (b, c, d, a, Block[ 6], 23,  $4881d05);
  HH (a, b, c, d, Block[ 9],  4, $d9d4d039);
  HH (d, a, b, c, Block[12], 11, $e6db99e5);
  HH (c, d, a, b, Block[15], 16, $1fa27cf8);
  HH (b, c, d, a, Block[ 2], 23, $c4ac5665);
  II (a, b, c, d, Block[ 0],  6, $f4292244);
  II (d, a, b, c, Block[ 7], 10, $432aff97);
  II (c, d, a, b, Block[14], 15, $ab9423a7);
  II (b, c, d, a, Block[ 5], 21, $fc93a039);
  II (a, b, c, d, Block[12],  6, $655b59c3);
  II (d, a, b, c, Block[ 3], 10, $8f0ccc92);
  II (c, d, a, b, Block[10], 15, $ffeff47d);
  II (b, c, d, a, Block[ 1], 21, $85845dd1);
  II (a, b, c, d, Block[ 8],  6, $6fa87e4f);
  II (d, a, b, c, Block[15], 10, $fe2ce6e0);
  II (c, d, a, b, Block[ 6], 15, $a3014314);
  II (b, c, d, a, Block[13], 21, $4e0811a1);
  II (a, b, c, d, Block[ 4],  6, $f7537e82);
  II (d, a, b, c, Block[11], 10, $bd3af235);
  II (c, d, a, b, Block[ 2], 15, $2ad7d2bb);
  II (b, c, d, a, Block[ 9], 21, $eb86d391);
  inc(State[0], a);
  inc(State[1], b);
  inc(State[2], c);
  inc(State[3], d);
end;

procedure MD5Init(var Context: MD5Context);
begin
  with Context do begin
    State[0] := $67452301;
    State[1] := $efcdab89;
    State[2] := $98badcfe;
    State[3] := $10325476;
    Count[0] := 0;
    Count[1] := 0;
    ZeroMemory(@Buffer, SizeOf(MD5Buffer));
  end;
end;

procedure MD5Update(var Context: MD5Context; Input: pChar; Length: longword);
var
  Index: longword;
  PartLen: longword;
  I: longword;
begin
  with Context do begin
    Index := (Count[0] shr 3) and $3f;
    inc(Count[0], Length shl 3);
    if Count[0] < (Length shl 3) then inc(Count[1]);
    inc(Count[1], Length shr 29);
  end;
  PartLen := 64 - Index;
  if Length >= PartLen then begin
    CopyMemory(@Context.Buffer[Index], Input, PartLen);
    Transform(@Context.Buffer, Context.State);
    I := PartLen;
    while I + 63 < Length do begin
      Transform(@Input[I], Context.State);
      inc(I, 64);
    end;
    Index := 0;
  end else I := 0;
  CopyMemory(@Context.Buffer[Index], @Input[I], Length - I);
end;

procedure MD5Final(var Context: MD5Context; var Digest: MD5Digest);
var
  Bits: MD5CBits;
  Index: longword;
  PadLen: longword;
begin
  Decode(@Context.Count, @Bits, 2);
  Index := (Context.Count[0] shr 3) and $3f;
  if Index < 56 then PadLen := 56 - Index else PadLen := 120 - Index;
  MD5Update(Context, @PADDING, PadLen);
  MD5Update(Context, @Bits, 8);
  Decode(@Context.State, @Digest, 4);
  ZeroMemory(@Context, SizeOf(MD5Context));
end;

function MD5String(M: string): MD5Digest;
var
  Context: MD5Context;
begin
  MD5Init(Context);
  MD5Update(Context, pChar(M), length(M));
  MD5Final(Context, Result);
end;



function MD5File(N: string): MD5Digest;
var
  FileHandle: THandle;
  MapHandle: THandle;
  ViewPointer: pointer;
  Context: MD5Context;
begin
  MD5Init(Context);
  FileHandle := CreateFile(pChar(N), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL or FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, 0);
  if FileHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then try
    MapHandle := CreateFileMapping(FileHandle, nil, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, nil);
    if MapHandle <> 0 then try
      ViewPointer := MapViewOfFile(MapHandle, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
      if ViewPointer <> nil then try
        MD5Update(Context, ViewPointer, GetFileSize(FileHandle, nil));
      finally
        UnmapViewOfFile(ViewPointer);
      end;
    finally
      CloseHandle(MapHandle);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(FileHandle);
  end;
  MD5Final(Context, Result);
end;

function MD5Print(D: MD5Digest): string;
var
  I: byte;
const
  Digits: array[0..15] of char =
    ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
begin
  Result := '';
  for I := 0 to 15 do Result := Result + Digits[(D[I] shr 4) and $0f] + Digits[D[I] and $0f];
end;


function MD5Match(D1, D2: MD5Digest): boolean;
var
  I: byte;
begin
  I := 0;
  Result := TRUE;
  while Result and (I < 16) do begin
    Result := D1[I] = D2[I];
    inc(I);
  end;
end;

function RivestStr(Str: string): string;
begin
  Result := MD5Print(MD5String(Str));
end;

function RivestFile(FileName: string): string;
begin
  Result := MD5Print(MD5File(FileName));
end;



end.
```

Answer (score 6):

What you are encountering is the difference between hashing 8bit Ansi data versus 16bit Unicode data.  Your old code expects Ansi data, your new code is operating on Unicode data instead.  Hashing is done on raw bytes, not on characters, so you are not hashing the same data, that is why you get different results.

Indy operates on Delphi's default `String` type, which is `AnsiString` in Delphi 2007 and earlier, but is `UnicodeString` in Delphi 2009 and later.

When hashing Unicode string data, you need to first convert the data to a specific byte encoding before you can then hash it.  Your old code ignores that step because it was not written to take Unicode into account, it assumes `AnsiString` is being used and hashes the raw string data as-is.

The `TIdHashMessageDigest5.HashString...()` methods have an optional `ADestEncoding` parameter so you can specify the desired byte encoding that input Unicode data is to be converted to before hashing the resulting bytes, eg:

```
function MD5Hash(Value : String) : String;
var
  workHash : TIdHashMessageDigest5;
begin
  workHash := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
  try
    // You can use whatever byte encoding you need. Indy's OSDefault
    // encoding is the same Ansi encoding used by AnsiString on Windows
    // (but is UTF-8 on other platforms). Note that converting Unicode
    // data to Ansi is a potentially lossy conversion, so you should
    // usually be using a loss-less encoding instead, such as UTF-8...
    //
    Result := workHash.HashStringAsHex(Value, IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(workHash);
  end;
end;
```

If you do not specify a byte encoding, Indy's default byte encoding is used, and that is set to US-ASCII by default (you can change that using the global `GIdDefaultTextEncoding` variable in the `IdGlobal` unit).

In Delphi 2007 and earlier, where `string` is `AnsiString`, the input string is first converted from Ansi to Unicode before then converted from Unicode to bytes.  So the `HashString...()` methods also have an optional `ASrcEncoding` parameter that you can use to specify the actual character encoding being used by the `AnsiString` if it is different than the OS's default character encoding.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `RivestStr` function was designed to work with 8bit Ansi data.  `AnsiString` and `PAnsiChar` were the default string/character types in Delphi versions prior to 2009.  Newer Delphi versions, like Berlin, use 16bit Unicode strings/characters as the default now.

Hashing is done on raw bytes, so you will get different results when creating a hash string from an 8bit string versus a 16bit Unicode string, even though both of them contain the same printable characters.

In fact, the way it is designed, your `RivestStr()` function and its underlying `MD5String` methods are returning wrong results to you when compiled with modern Delphi versions, like Berlin.

You can check this by making the same test application (same code) in an older Delphi version prior to 2009, and in Delphi Berlin, and you will see that you are getting different results.

Now, how to fix your problem?

In your MD5 unit you need to replace all occurrences of:

- `string` with `AnsiString`.
- `char` with `AnsiChar`.
- `PChar` with `PAnsiChar`.

The only exceptions would be:

- the `N` parameter of the `MD5File` method
- the `pChar` typecast of `N` withing the `CreateFile()` call.

If you decide to also change these, don't forget to replace the `CreateFile()` call with `CreateFileA()` instead so it is expecting an Ansi string as input for the given file name.